# Corman exercice :Random(a, b)

Tags: algorithm, random

I don't understand the answer of this exercise , especially why they take

```
n = [log(b - a +1 )] ?!!
```

I think `n = ceil(log2(b))`

---

Here is the exercise:

> Describe an implementation of **RANDOM(a, b)** that only makes calls to **RANDOM (0, 1)** .

and the answer :

```
1: n = [lg(b − a + 1)] 
2: Initialize an array A of length n
3: while true do
4:    for i = 1 to n do
5:       A[i] = RANDOM(0, 1)
6:    end for
7:    if A holds the binary representation of one of the numbers in a through
b     then
8:          return number represented by A
9:    end if
10: end while
```

link of page : http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~ajl213/CLRS/CLRS.html

Answer (score 1):

It backs to the decimal method. When you want map a number from `(0,1)` to `(a,b)`, you just need multiply the number in `(b-a)` and then plus `a`. It means if we have a number `x` in `(a,b)`, we will have `(b-a)*x + a` which maps `0` to `a` and `1` to `b`.

As plus `a` is a linear shift for all numbers, this shift is ignored here. Hence, the biggest value is `b-a` and the number of values between the close set of `[a,b]` is `b-a+1`.

Comment: thank for your answer, I thought that the biggest value was b and in this case we need log2(b) bit for coding decimal value

Comment: @AzizChafik if it works for you, you can accept this as an answer to your question.